[split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libflutter.so]
Android users are repeatedly facing issues, and I'm experiencing problems with the Google Play Console in my Flutter app
Thread
[FATAL:flutter/shell/platform/android/platform_view_android_jni_impl.cc(1594)] Check failed: fml::jni::CheckException(env).

pid: 0, tid: 4648 >>> com.namp.zeon <<<
backtrace:
#00  pc 0x0000000000066b38  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (abort+164)
#01  pc 0x0000000000438784  /data/app/~~-UlEpQ6qirxCYTCsp2cKQ==/com.namp.zeon-nLGHOEsPFsiSnlkpiAbnRg==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libflutter.so (BuildId: 81eff0ad9315d43a8c67226d6b08171218431655)
#02  pc 0x0000000000465408  /data/app/~~-UlEpQ6qirxCYTCsp2cKQ==/com.namp.zeon-nLGHOEsPFsiSnlkpiAbnRg==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libflutter.so (BuildId: 81eff0ad9315d43a8c67226d6b08171218431655)
#03  pc 0x0000000000451c5c  /data/app/~~-UlEpQ6qirxCYTCsp2cKQ==/com.namp.zeon-nLGHOEsPFsiSnlkpiAbnRg==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libflutter.so (BuildId: 81eff0ad9315d43a8c67226d6b08171218431655)
#04  pc 0x0000000000448db8  /data/app/~~-UlEpQ6qirxCYTCsp2cKQ==/com.namp.zeon-nLGHOEsPFsiSnlkpiAbnRg==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libflutter.so (BuildId: 81eff0ad9315d43a8c67226d6b08171218431655)
#05  pc 0x0000000000448eac  /data/app/~~-UlEpQ6qirxCYTCsp2cKQ==/com.namp.zeon-nLGHOEsPFsiSnlkpiAbnRg==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libflutter.so (BuildId: 81eff0ad9315d43a8c67226d6b08171218431655)
#06  pc 0x0000000000449180  /data/app/~~-UlEpQ6qirxCYTCsp2cKQ==/com.namp.zeon-nLGHOEsPFsiSnlkpiAbnRg==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libflutter.so (BuildId: 81eff0ad9315d43a8c67226d6b08171218431655)
#07  pc 0x0000000000448b74  /data/app/~~-UlEpQ6qirxCYTCsp2cKQ==/com.namp.zeon-nLGHOEsPFsiSnlkpiAbnRg==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libflutter.so (BuildId: 81eff0ad9315d43a8c67226d6b08171218431655)
#08  pc 0x00000000006d141c  /data/app/~~-UlEpQ6qirxCYTCsp2cKQ==/com.namp.zeon-nLGHOEsPFsiSnlkpiAbnRg==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libflutter.so (BuildId: 81eff0ad9315d43a8c67226d6b08171218431655)
#09  pc 0x00000000006cc9e4  /data/app/~~-UlEpQ6qirxCYTCsp2cKQ==/com.namp.zeon-nLGHOEsPFsiSnlkpiAbnRg==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libflutter.so (BuildId: 81eff0ad9315d43a8c67226d6b08171218431655)
#10  pc 0x00000000006d166c  /data/app/~~-UlEpQ6qirxCYTCsp2cKQ==/com.namp.zeon-nLGHOEsPFsiSnlkpiAbnRg==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libflutter.so (BuildId: 81eff0ad9315d43a8c67226d6b08171218431655)
#11  pc 0x00000000006cc9e4  /data/app/~~-UlEpQ6qirxCYTCsp2cKQ==/com.namp.zeon-nLGHOEsPFsiSnlkpiAbnRg==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libflutter.so (BuildId: 81eff0ad9315d43a8c67226d6b08171218431655)
#12  pc 0x00000000006d166c  /data/app/~~-UlEpQ6qirxCYTCsp2cKQ==/com.namp.zeon-nLGHOEsPFsiSnlkpiAbnRg==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libflutter.so (BuildId: 81eff0ad9315d43a8c67226d6b08171218431655)
#13  pc 0x00000000006cc9e4  /data/app/~~-UlEpQ6qirxCYTCsp2cKQ==/com.namp.zeon-nLGHOEsPFsiSnlkpiAbnRg==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libflutter.so (BuildId: 81eff0ad9315d43a8c67226d6b08171218431655)
#14  pc 0x00000000006d166c  /data/app/~~-UlEpQ6qirxCYTCsp2cKQ==/com.namp.zeon-nLGHOEsPFsiSnlkpiAbnRg==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libflutter.so (BuildId: 81eff0ad9315d43a8c67226d6b08171218431655)
#15  pc 0x00000000006cc9e4  /data/app/~~-UlEpQ6qirxCYTCsp2cKQ==/com.namp.zeon-nLGHOEsPFsiSnlkpiAbnRg==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libflutter.so (BuildId: 81eff0ad9315d43a8c67226d6b08171218431655)
#16  pc 0x00000000006d166c  /data/app/~~-UlEpQ6qirxCYTCsp2cKQ==/com.namp.zeon-nLGHOEsPFsiSnlkpiAbnRg==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libflutter.so (BuildId: 81eff0ad9315d43a8c67226d6b08171218431655)
#17  pc 0x00000000006cc9e4  /data/app/~~-UlEpQ6qirxCYTCsp2cKQ==/com.namp.zeon-nLGHOEsPFsiSnlkpiAbnRg==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libflutter.so (BuildId: 81eff0ad9315d43a8c67226d6b08171218431655)
#18  pc 0x00000000006cff64  /data/app/~~-UlEpQ6qirxCYTCsp2cKQ==/com.namp.zeon-nLGHOEsPFsiSnlkpiAbnRg==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libflutter.so (BuildId: 81eff0ad9315d43a8c67226d6b08171218431655)
#19  pc 0x00000000006ca92c  /data/app/~~-UlEpQ6qirxCYTCsp2cKQ==/com.namp.zeon-nLGHOEsPFsiSnlkpiAbnRg==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libflutter.so (BuildId: 81eff0ad9315d43a8c67226d6b08171218431655)
#20  pc 0x000000000078fbf0  /data/app/~~-UlEpQ6qirxCYTCsp2cKQ==/com.namp.zeon-nLGHOEsPFsiSnlkpiAbnRg==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libflutter.so (BuildId: 81eff0ad9315d43a8c67226d6b08171218431655)
#21  pc 0x000000000078f718  /data/app/~~-UlEpQ6qirxCYTCsp2cKQ==/com.namp.zeon-nLGHOEsPFsiSnlkpiAbnRg==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libflutter.so (BuildId: 81eff0ad9315d43a8c67226d6b08171218431655)
#22  pc 0x0000000000790a00  /data/app/~~-UlEpQ6qirxCYTCsp2cKQ==/com.namp.zeon-nLGHOEsPFsiSnlkpiAbnRg==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libflutter.so (BuildId: 81eff0ad9315d43a8c67226d6b08171218431655)
#23  pc 0x0000000000790504  /data/app/~~-UlEpQ6qirxCYTCsp2cKQ==/com.namp.zeon-nLGHOEsPFsiSnlkpiAbnRg==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libflutter.so (BuildId: 81eff0ad9315d43a8c67226d6b08171218431655)
#24  pc 0x000000000079c310  /data/app/~~-UlEpQ6qirxCYTCsp2cKQ==/com.namp.zeon-nLGHOEsPFsiSnlkpiAbnRg==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libflutter.so (BuildId: 81eff0ad9315d43a8c67226d6b08171218431655)
#25  pc 0x0000000000466000  /data/app/~~-UlEpQ6qirxCYTCsp2cKQ==/com.namp.zeon-nLGHOEsPFsiSnlkpiAbnRg==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libflutter.so (BuildId: 81eff0ad9315d43a8c67226d6b08171218431655)
#26  pc 0x0000000000469d54  /data/app/~~-UlEpQ6qirxCYTCsp2cKQ==/com.namp.zeon-nLGHOEsPFsiSnlkpiAbnRg==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libflutter.so (BuildId: 81eff0ad9315d43a8c67226d6b08171218431655)
#27  pc 0x0000000000019300  /system/lib64/libutils.so (android::Looper::pollInner(int)+1248)
#28  pc 0x0000000000018dc0  /system/lib64/libutils.so (android::Looper::pollOnce(int, int*, int*, void**)+120)
#29  pc 0x0000000000021ddc  /system/lib64/libandroid.so (ALooper_pollOnce+100)
#30  pc 0x0000000000469e64  /data/app/~~-UlEpQ6qirxCYTCsp2cKQ==/com.namp.zeon-nLGHOEsPFsiSnlkpiAbnRg==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libflutter.so (BuildId: 81eff0ad9315d43a8c67226d6b08171218431655)
#31  pc 0x0000000000467d40  /data/app/~~-UlEpQ6qirxCYTCsp2cKQ==/com.namp.zeon-nLGHOEsPFsiSnlkpiAbnRg==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libflutter.so (BuildId: 81eff0ad9315d43a8c67226d6b08171218431655)
#32  pc 0x00000000000cb888  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+208)
#33  pc 0x0000000000068370  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__start_thread+64)
reduce the crash error in system

defaultConfig {
    multiDexEnabled true
    applicationId "com.example.app"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 34
    versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
    versionName flutterVersionName
    ndk {
    abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a', 'x86_64'
    }
}
buildTypes {
   release {
       signingConfig signingConfigs.release
       minifyEnabled true
       proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
       shrinkResources true
       debuggable false
       jniDebuggable false
       renderscriptDebuggable false
       pseudoLocalesEnabled false
       zipAlignEnabled true
       ndk {
        abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a', 'x86_64'
        }
   }
 }

Add this lined to the build.gradle file. It will solve the issue

Hello, could you specify which parameters in your sample code are effective?

the ndk key in both
